# How can i draw a straight vertical line on tradingview chart library

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

I'm using the Tradingview LightWeight Chart library, I would like to draw a vertical line just like the one in the image below, how do I go about it?

I've tried setting the chart to show only one date and activate the grid but I also don't know how to make the chart show only one date. My plan was to make the chart show just one date and activate the grid, that way, I get the vertical Line.

[image]

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77749108/vertical-lines-in-lightweight-charts-how-to-implement-them-from-plugins/78238785

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the LightWeight charts don't expose an API for that.

The closest thing you can do is to use the `addHistogramSeries` (which is typically used to show volume bars). You will need to set `scaleMargins: { top: 0, bottom: 0 }` and that will generate bars with the 100% height. Considering that they can be semi-transparent that will be close enough to a vertical bar.

Check out the screenshot:

[image]

The yellow bars are produced using that technique, and btw the blue bars on the top are also created the same way with `scaleMargins: { top: 0, bottom: 0.98 }` settings.

Comment: ok, thanks ill do it like you said